# facebook javascript sdk check if user is fan (Error: invalid version specified)

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I have write this code to know if user fan of the page, but it showing (Error: invalid version specified)

```
FB.api({
    method:     'fql.query', 
    query:  'SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid=user_id AND page_id=page_id'
}, function(resp) {
    if (resp.length) {
        alert('A fan!')
    } else {
        alert('Not a fan!');
    }
}
);
```

Any one can help me, please help me

Comment: FQL is deprecated. Use Graph API instead

Comment: FYI: Facebook doesn’t allow “like gating” any more. To see if a user is a fan of a specific page, you’d need `user_likes` permission – and Facebook will not grant you usage of that in review for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error probably because you are using version 2.1 or 2.2 of Facebook Platform API, where FQL got deprecated (read more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql)).

As mentioned above you should use Graph API with a similar call:

```
FB.api(
    "/{user-id}/likes/{page-id}",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

If specified user is a fan of given page the Page Object will be returned, if not there will be an empty dataset.